# How can I apply a custom shape of TextInputLayout in both the state, Focused and normal state without using librery

Tags: android, widget, android-textinputlayout, material-components-android, material-components

I wanna design a custom rounded corner TextInputLayout 
As I shown my sample image of active TextInputLayout [image]below

My code in xml is

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/mobile_number"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_regular"
                android:maxLength="10" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Its getting me a default TextInputLayout. How can I get my view.Please help me out.
Getting error in style declaration.
[image: error in style declaration]

Answer (score 7):

Just use the `Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox` style and apply a custom shape:

```
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        style="@style/OutlinedRoundedBox"
        ...>
```

with:

```
 <style name="OutlinedRoundedBox" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
    <item name="shapeAppearanceOverlay">
      @style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MyApp.TextInputLayout.Rounded
    </item>
  </style>

  <style name="ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MyApp.TextInputLayout.Rounded" parent="">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">32dp</item>
  </style>
```

[image]

Comment: Sir I'm getting error in style declaration. As  I shown screenshot in above question. Kindly check that again.

Comment: Thank you so much sir for your support. My style.xml file would be like this.    `<style name="OutlinedRoundBox" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
        <item name="boxBackgroundMode">outline</item>
        <item name="boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd">32dp</item>
        <item name="boxCornerRadiusBottomStart">32dp</item>
        <item name="boxCornerRadiusTopEnd">32dp</item>
        <item name="boxCornerRadiusTopStart">32dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">20dp</item>
    </style>`

Comment: To solve your issue, you have to use the version 1.1.0

Answer (score 1):

If you want to implement design without using third liberary. just create a style like this:

```
<style name="OutlinedRoundBox" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
    <item name="boxBackgroundMode">outline</item>
    <item name="boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd">32dp</item>
    <item name="boxCornerRadiusBottomStart">32dp</item>
    <item name="boxCornerRadiusTopEnd">32dp</item>
    <item name="boxCornerRadiusTopStart">32dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">20dp</item>
</style>
```

[image: Achieved design/ result]

Comment: this is not working for me in version 1.3.0, Android 11